# Android Lock Screen

Tags: code-golf, number, combinatorics

### Intro

You are sitting in a board room at the end of a long table. You look around and see Tim Cook, the Apple Board of Directors, the ghost of Steve Jobs, and Jack Donaghy. Apple has called this meeting because they have realized how much cooler the Android lock screen is, and they want to 1-UP them. Everyone in the room stares at you as Ghost Steve cries, "Help me, CodeGolf Man! You're my only hope!"

### The Problem

The Android lock screen is a 3 x 3 grid of dots that can be connected by swiping a finger from one dot to the next, creating a path. A password is considered any possible path that includes any number of dots, and excludes any number of dots. (On an actual phone, the path must be at least 4 dots long. For this challenge, ignore that restriction.) Apple plans to replace the 3 x 3 grid with an M x N grid, which is (M*N)/9 times better!

Rules:

A zero dot path is not a password, but a 1 dot path is

A path can cross itself

A path cannot cross directly over a dot without including that dot

A dot can only be used once

Paths that are identical by rotation are not the same password

Paths that are identical but ordered in reverse are not the same password

For example, on a 3x3 grid with dots numbered from 1 to 9:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Some valid paths are:

```
1
3
7,2,3
1,5,9,2
1,8,6,5,4
4,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
5,9,6,4
```

And some invalid paths are:

```
1,3
1,9,5
7,5,4,7
4,6
```

Your input will be three numbers:

```
(M,N,d)
```

Where the grid is M x N, and d is the length of the path

```
1 <= M <= 16
1 <= N <= 16
1 <= d <= M * N
```

Your program or function will be given the input as a comma separated string, and it must return the number of possible passwords of that length. For example:

```
Input:  2,2,1 
Output: 4
Input:  2,2,2
Output: 12
Input:  7,4,1
Output: 28
```

Standard code golf rules apply, shortest code wins!

```
//If I've made a mistake or the rules are unclear, please correct me!
```

Comment: You said "your **program** must return...", but in your example you have provided something that resembles a **function**. It may be better to reword your question so that it is either *a program*, or *a function*, or *a program or a function*.

Comment: It that more clear? This is my first question, so I'm not 100% clear on the specifics.

Comment: Is the input a comma-separated string or three separate parameters?

Comment: @user80551 Based on the context, I think it will be a string if it is input to a program, or separate parameters if it is used to call the function.

Comment: @Platatat can you please answer user80551's question, as this is really important to design the code

Comment: Let's say the input is a comma separated string

Comment: You should decide if there's going to be a time limit for both the compile and execution time of a given solution. Without such a limit, it's easy to write a program that, in theory, verifies which of all `256!` permutations of the dots on the 16 x 16 grid represent a valid unlock pattern. In practice, such a program would never terminate.

Comment: What about the same paths in reverse order ? `d` must be greater or equal. I think you should remove movements like `7,2` (not neighbours) and `5,6,4` (overlapping), they add difficulty to an already hard challenge.

Comment: can you explain why `5,9,6,4` is considered a valid path? it appears you are crossing over (but not including) `5` to get from `6` to `4`

Comment: Yes, you are crossing over 5, but since 5 has already been used it isn't considered illegal. "A path cannot cross directly over a dot without including that dot" was as best as I could word this, and basically since this path DOES use 5 before it jumps over it, the path is legal. This is how actual android phones work, too.

Comment: Just because it's how it works in Android doesn't mean it's interesting in the context of code golf. There was a typo in my previous comment, `d` must be superior or equal to *2*.

Comment: But I said the problem was based on the android lock system... So why shouldn't I use the same rules as the android lock system?

Answer (score 14):

### Python - 170 bytes

```
from fractions import*
p=lambda m,n,d,l=0,s=set():d<1or sum([p(m,n,d-1,i,s|{i})for i in range(m*n)if not(s and(s&{i}or set(range(l,i,abs(i-l)/gcd(i%n-l%n,i/n-l/n)))-s))])
```

I realize that the brackets inside `sum([...])` are not strictly necessary, but there's a large performance penalty for not including them.

Output for all 3x3s:

```
for i in range(4, 10):
  print p(3, 3, i)
```

Produces:

```
1624
7152
26016
72912
140704
140704
```

For testing/confirmation purposes, the first 6 values for a 4x5 board:

```
20
262
3280
39644
459764
5101232
```

4x5 is an interesting case to verify, because it has 2x2, 3x3, and 2x4 peg jumps.

---

#### Brief Explanation

In general, this is an exhaustive search, with cumulative pruning. For example, because `p(3, 3, 4)` is 1624, `p(3, 3, 5)` will only check 8120 posibilities, rather than naïvely checking all 15120. Most of the logic is contained in the condition:

```
if not(s and(s&{i}or set(range(l,i,abs(i-l)/gcd(i%n-l%n,i/n-l/n)))-s))
```

In plain english, this can be understood as:

```
If no pegs have been used yet
     OR
   the target peg has not yet been used
     AND
   each of the pegs directly between the target peg and the
   current peg (a.k.a. "jumped over") have already been used
```

Comment: Could you explain what in the world is going on here?

Comment: You can save a few bytes by having `s` be a set instead of a list. I'm not seeing the large performance penalty of dropping the brackets; why would there be such a penalty?

Comment: @user2357112 one is summing over a Generator, the other over a List. With CPython, you're right, there isn't much difference (only about 20% slower). With PyPy, it's over 5 times as slow.

Comment: @user2357112 I finally see what you meant by defining `s` as a set. My python lesson for today: `{i}` evaluates as `set([i])`. I would have expected a syntax error. Appending an item to a set then becomes `s|{i}`, and it also allows `i in s` to be replaced by `s&{i}`.